# How to get previous page reference/alias in extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I am working in extjs4 MVC.And here I am get a stuck at point where I want to display page , on that page suppose there is link.And after clicking on link of first view I am going to redirected to another view.My requirement is I want to get reference or alias name of first view or alias when I am going to click on second views button.

here is view  code:-
1) first view :--

```
Ext.define('App.view.left.WordOfTheDay',    {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.WordOfTheDay',
    localized:true,

    xMore:"more",
    xTitle:"Word Of The Day",
    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            title:this.xTitle,

            items:[
                   {
                     xtype:'panel',
                     html:'<br>sdf<br>sdfsdf<br>sdsddf<br><a href="#" id="wordOfDay">'+this.xMore+'</a>',
                   }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});// End of login class
```

and its design
[image]
2)second view design:-

### [image]

After clicking on first view it displays second view.And when I am clicking on second views keylogin button I want to get reference of first view or alias of first view..
I worked on it but I did not get solution for it.Please give me some guide line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to assign an unique id to each view, then use [Ext.ComponentManager.get('view-id')](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentManager-method-get) to get the reference. For example:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel1', {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
  xtype: 'mypanel1',

  id: 'my-panel-1',
  html: 'Panel 1 <a href="#">Go</a>',

  initComponent: function() {
    this.on('afterrender', function() {
      this.getEl().down('a').on('click', function() {
        Ext.ComponentManager.get('my-panel-2').show(); // go to second view
        this.hide();
      }, this);
    }, this);
  }
});

Ext.define('MyPanel2', {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
  xtype: 'mypanel2',

  id: 'my-panel-2',
  html: 'Panel 2 <a href="#">Back</a>',

  initComponent: function() {
    this.on('afterrender', function() {
      this.getEl().down('a').on('click', function() {
        Ext.ComponentManager.get('my-panel-1').show(); // back to first view
        this.hide();
      }, this);
    }, this);
  }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'mypanel1',
      },
      {
        xtype: 'mypanel2',
        hidden: true,
      }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });
});
```

[Try it](http://plnkr.co/oXNTrP) on Plunker